# Universal script for moving elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a universal code for easy moving elements in DOM between desktop and mobile. It's not my idea as well as not my code. It was for Prestashop 1.7 only, but I want to change it for any project.

The idea is that you can wrap some code you want to move in an absolute different place on mobile with `<div id="_desktop_some-block">Some content</div>`, and place empty `<div id="_mobile_some-block"></div>` where you want to see it on mobile devices and when window reach (for ex.) 768px the HTML of the element will be moving to another one.

**So here is an original code:**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import prestashop from 'prestashop';

prestashop.responsive = prestashop.responsive || {};

prestashop.responsive.current_width = window.innerWidth;
prestashop.responsive.min_width = 768;
prestashop.responsive.mobile = prestashop.responsive.current_width < prestashop.responsive.min_width;

function swapChildren(obj1, obj2)
{
    var temp = obj2.children().detach();
    obj2.empty().append(obj1.children().detach());
    obj1.append(temp);
}

function toggleMobileStyles()
{
    if (prestashop.responsive.mobile) {
        $("*[id^='_desktop_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.id.replace('_desktop_', '_mobile_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("*[id^='_mobile_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.id.replace('_mobile_', '_desktop_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    }
    prestashop.emit('responsive update', {
        mobile: prestashop.responsive.mobile
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var _cw = prestashop.responsive.current_width;
    var _mw = prestashop.responsive.min_width;
    var _w = window.innerWidth;
    var _toggle = (_cw >= _mw && _w < _mw) || (_cw < _mw && _w >= _mw);
    prestashop.responsive.current_width = _w;
    prestashop.responsive.mobile = prestashop.responsive.current_width < prestashop.responsive.min_width;
    if (_toggle) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (prestashop.responsive.mobile) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});
```

**Here is what I'm trying to do:**

```
var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
var windowMinWidth = 768;
var windowResponsiveMobile = windowWidth < windowMinWidth;

function swapChildren(obj1, obj2)
{
    var temp = obj2.children().detach();
    obj2.empty().append(obj1.children().detach());
    obj1.append(temp);
}

function toggleMobileStyles()
{
    if (windowResponsiveMobile) {
        $("*[id^='_desktop_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.replace('_desktop_', '_mobile_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("*[id^='_mobile_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.replace('_mobile_', '_desktop_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var _cw = windowWidth;
    var _mw = windowMinWidth;
    var _w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var _toggle = (_cw >= _mw && _w < _mw) || (_cw < _mw && _w >= _mw);
    windowWidth = _w;
    windowResponsiveMobile = windowWidth < windowMinWidth;
    if (_toggle) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (windowResponsiveMobile) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});
```

Currently it doesn't work, but I don't see any errors in the console and it little bit confuse...

Please help me to finish it so it could work.

Comment: Why not just CSS media queries?

Comment: well, I think that display:none/block for elements is not good practice. I could do it, but it's not so interesting )

Comment: Media queries give you the ability to override as little or as much CSS as you want, depending on the device properties.  It's not display:block/none - it's *all* CSS.

Comment: Media queries is a better practice than a big JS chunk... For mobiles and tablets. And it accuratly handles screen orientation too. No need to script a `resize`.

Comment: I see guys, but what if you need to move a block from footer to header? And what if this block contains quite much info? I have to place it in both sections and apply for one of them display: none; and only on mobile do it display: block; as well as for different one I have to apply display: none;

Comment: About to "move" a block... You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which "normally" appends new content to a selected element... **BUT**, also can "move" an already in DOM element to another place, since an element only can be at one place... ;) That would be `$("newPlaceSelector").append("elementToMoveSelector");` Look for [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
var windowMinWidth = 768;
var windowResponsiveMobile = windowWidth < windowMinWidth;

function swapChildren(obj1, obj2)
{
    var temp = obj2.children().detach();
    obj2.empty().append(obj1.children().detach());
    obj1.append(temp);
}

function toggleMobileStyles()
{
    if (windowResponsiveMobile) {
        $("[id^='_desktop_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.id.replace('_desktop_', '_mobile_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("[id^='_mobile_']").each(function(idx, el) {
            var target = $('#' + el.id.replace('_mobile_', '_desktop_'));
            if (target.length) {
                swapChildren($(el), target);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var _cw = windowWidth;
    var _mw = windowMinWidth;
    var _w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var _toggle = (_cw >= _mw && _w < _mw) || (_cw < _mw && _w >= _mw);
    windowWidth = _w;
    windowResponsiveMobile = windowWidth < windowMinWidth;
    if (_toggle) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (windowResponsiveMobile) {
        toggleMobileStyles();
    }
});
```

Here is the updated code, you just removed the `id` in the target selector.